# Swift - Receiving Null Island Error In Console

Tags: swift, swiftui, concurrency, mapkit, core-location

I am displaying a map in a view showing a pin location of an address.

Here's what I've got:

```
import Combine
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct MapViewLocation: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

struct MapViewSmall: View {
    @State var address: String
    @State private var mapCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = nil
    @State private var mapIsLoading: Bool = true
    @State private var mapLocations: [MapViewLocation] = []
    @State private var mapRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()
    @State private var mapSuccess: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if mapIsLoading {
                ProgressView()
                    .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
                    .scaleEffect(0.8)
            } else {
                if self.mapSuccess {
                    Map(
                        coordinateRegion: $mapRegion,
                        interactionModes: [.pan],
                        annotationItems: mapLocations,
                        annotationContent: { location in
                            MapPin(
                                coordinate: self.mapCoordinate ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D(),
                                tint: .red
                            )
                        }
                    )
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .cornerRadius(9)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
                        request.naturalLanguageQuery = self.address
                        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
                        search.start { response, error in
                            if let response = response {
                                let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: response.mapItems[0].placemark)
                                mapItem.name = self.address
                                mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "mappin.slash.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.mapIsLoading = true
            Task {
                await self.makeMap()
            }
        }

    }

func getLocation(address: String, completion: @escaping (_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?) -> Void) {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            guard let placemarks = placemarks,
            let location = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            completion(location)
        } 
    }

    func makeMap() async {

        // Convert the address
        self.getLocation(address: self.address) { location in

            // Handle Bad Address Errors
            if location == nil {
                self.mapSuccess = false
                self.mapIsLoading = false
                return
            }

            self.mapCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                                    latitude: location?.latitude ?? 0.0,
                                    longitude: location?.longitude ?? 0.0
                                )

            // Set the Region
            self.mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
                                center: self.mapCoordinate ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D(),
                                span: MKCoordinateSpan(
                                    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                                    longitudeDelta: 0.01
                                )
                            )

            // Create the MapViewLocation
            self.mapLocations.append(
                MapViewLocation(
                    coordinate: self.mapCoordinate ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D()
                )
            )

            // Set the Loading State
            self.mapSuccess = true
            self.mapIsLoading = false

        }
    }

}

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MapViewSmall(address: "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino CA 95014, United States")
    }
}
```

The errors in the console when I go to the view are:

> 2023-01-05 16:22:05.512925-0600 BLAH[14113:3111741] [Client] {"msg":"#NullIsland Received a latitude or longitude from getLocationForBundleID that was exactly zero", "latIsZero":0, "lonIsZero":0, "location":{"floor":2147483647,"lifespan":-1,"rawLat":0,"integrity":0,"referenceFrame":"Unknown","lon":0,"speed":-1,"type":"Unknown","altitude":0,"rawCourse":-1,"confidence":0,"suitability":{"type":"decode failure","raw value":1797990240,"expected type":"CLClientLocationSuitability"},"ellipsoidalAltitude":0,"timestamp":-1,"rawReferenceFrame":"Unknown","lat":4.9406564584124654e-324,"verticalAccuracy":-1,"rawLon":0,"horizontalAccuracy":-1,"speedAccuracy":-1,"courseAccuracy":-1,"fromSimulationController":false,"course":-1}}

> 2023-01-05 16:22:05.588983-0600 BLAH[14113:3111741] [core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)""

> 2023-01-05 16:22:05.875299-0600 BLAH[14113:3111397] [PipelineLibrary] Mapping the pipeline data cache failed, errno 22

---

I also tried rewriting the functions using Combine to see if that helped and nothing changed so I reverted back.

This all works and the user experience is great, but I would very much like to resolve the errors and understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952663/strange-nullisland-warning-from-coremotion-framework

Comment: I did. I am not using a simulator, I am using a real device. The solution that was presented discussed things that are not present when presenting a map, so it didn't seem like the correct solution.

Comment: You are checking for `nil` location, but you should also check for [`horizontalAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423599-horizontalaccuracy) that is negative. “A negative value indicates that the latitude and longitude are invalid.”

Comment: Appreciated but the latitude and longitude are not invalid. As I stated, the view works as it should. It's just throwing the errors in console which is what I'm trying to resolve. You can see in the code that the Map() doesn't even show until the function has completed and the mapSuccess variable is set to true. My guess is it's something in the makeMap function since it's running onAppear of the view, but I haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: It looks as though it received a location with a latitude and longitude that are exactly zero. This could be caused by a problem with the location services on the device, or by an issue with the location handling code.

Comment: You are misusing the async keyword that is for functions that use concurrency completion handlers are not concurrent

Comment: Not sure I agree with the misusing of the async keyword. The view hung on tap before the coordinates were returned and marking the method async solved the issue. I tried removing the async call and using Mark McKeon's answer of wrapping the onAppear in a DispatchQueue and sure, the view no longer hangs on load but I get the same console errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Task wrapper around the makeMap() function, because it is not necessary.

Add a onLongPressGesture modifier to the Map view, so that it can handle long press gestures.

Wrap the makeMap() function in a DispatchQueue.main.async block, to ensure that it is called on the main thread. This should fix the "Mapping the pipeline data cache failed, errno 22" error.

```
 .onAppear {
        self.mapIsLoading = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.makeMap()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just tried and no, it doesn't solve the pipeline error. I don't want a long press gesture, just a tap. Not looking to change the way the page works, just solve the console errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is nothing to do with displaying a map, it's generated when doing the geocoding. It seems like the geocoder likes to know where you are when it is geocoding, presumably so it can order results somehow. **If your app asks for in-use location permissions, the warning goes away**.

If you get console warnings you don't understand, it's always a good idea to set a breakpoint and step through the code to find out exactly where the error is generated.

Incidentally, you can rewrite `getLocation` like this:

```swift
func getLocation(address: String) async -> CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    do {
        let marks = try await geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address)
        return marks.first?.location?.coordinate
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And `makeMap()` like this:

```swift
@MainActor
func makeMap() async {

    // Convert the address
    let location = await getLocation(address: self.address)
    
    // Handle Bad Address Errors
    guard let location = location else {
        self.mapSuccess = false
        self.mapIsLoading = false
        return
    }

    self.mapCoordinate = location

    // Set the Region
    self.mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: location,
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(
            latitudeDelta: 0.01,
            longitudeDelta: 0.01
        )
    )

    // Create the MapViewLocation
    self.mapLocations.append(MapViewLocation(coordinate: location))
    
    // Set the Loading State
    self.mapSuccess = true
    self.mapIsLoading = false
}
```

Call it all from `.task` instead of `onAppear`:

```swift
.task {
    await self.makeMap()
}
```

Which makes your code a little cleaner.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same console errors appear. Your code works the same as mine did, but I still have the same error issues. Also, I never need to know where the user is so I don't ask for location permissions. This map is only for displaying an address that the user creates. Think of it like how Apple creates their contact info card and shows a small map of the address. I am working on a private/secure app so tracking the user's location would be a bad thing.

Comment: The console message is caused by the lack of location permissions, nothing else. If you don't want to ask for permissions, then you can just ignore the console message, I don't think there's much else you can do.

Comment: That's no problem. If it is literally console noise because I am not tracking the user's location (i.e. asking them for location permissions), that's totally cool. What about the pipeline error? Is that also the same issue?

Comment: I didn't see the pipeline error on my testing, but unfortunately the Xcode console seems to get noisier with every release, it makes it hard to find legitimate problems. I don't think you need to worry about this one.